# How does the filling of the 2p orbitals occur?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle, orbitals

When electrons enter the 2p orbitals, electrons of the same spin occupy the 2p orbitals first and then electrons of the opposite spin fill up the orbitals. Why is that? My professor told me that there is zero possibility of electrons occupying the same orbital with similar spin while there is a finite possibility of that happening when their spin is opposed. But this explanation is not quite clear to me. What is the explanation of this rule?

Comment: The downvoter should at least state the reason that why he/she thinks this is not a good question!

Comment: This is thoroughly explained in any atomic physics textbook. If that's too much to read, the Wikipedia pages on the Pauli exclusion principle and on Hund's rules cover it plenty well. Either way, this question is under-researched.

Comment: @ABcDexter: The answer can be easily traced by conceiving the exclusion principle and how two identical fermions interact with opposite phases. OP didn't show enough research-efforts; that's why I tagged it with [tag:pauli-exclusion-principle].

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Maybe the OP is unaware of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page). Both you and Mafia are right.